# Defined functions are not recognized by Python

Tags: python, conv-neural-network

I have an object called `network3` which contains the code that defines activation functions `linear` and `ReLu` and layer `ConvPoolLayer`:

```
### network3.py
# Libraries
import numpy as np
import theano
import theano.tensor as T
from theano.tensor.nnet import conv
from theano.tensor.nnet import softmax
from theano.tensor import shared_randomstreams
from theano.tensor.signal import pool

# Activation functions for neurons
def linear(z): return z
def ReLU(z): return T.maximum(0.0, z)
from theano.tensor.nnet import sigmoid
from theano.tensor import tanh
...
class ConvPoolLayer(object):
    def __init__(self, filter_shape, image_shape, poolsize=(2, 2), activation_fn=sigmoid):
    self.activation_fn=activation_fn
...
```

However, in Jupyter notebook, when I ran the following code:

```
import network3
from network3 import Network
from network3 import ConvPoolLayer , FullyConnectedLayer , SoftmaxLayer

net = Network([
    ConvPoolLayer(image_shape=(mini_batch_size , 1, 28, 28),
                  filter_shape=(20, 1, 5, 5),
                  poolsize=(2, 2),
                  activation_fn=ReLU),
    ConvPoolLayer(image_shape=(mini_batch_size , 20, 12, 12),
                  filter_shape=(40, 20, 5, 5),
                  poolsize=(2, 2),
                  activation_fn=ReLU),
    FullyConnectedLayer(n_in=40*4*4, n_out=100, activation_fn=ReLU),
    SoftmaxLayer(n_in=100, n_out=10)], 
    mini_batch_size)

net.SGD(expanded_training_data, 60, mini_batch_size, 0.03, 
        validation_data, test_data , lmbda=0.1)
```

It returned an error:

```
NameError                          Traceback (most recent call last)<ipython-input-4-55105ca84f86> in <module>
      5                   filter_shape=(20, 1, 5, 5),
      6                   poolsize=(2, 2),
----> 7                   activation_fn=ReLU),
      8     ConvPoolLayer(image_shape=(mini_batch_size , 20, 12, 12),
      9                   filter_shape=(40, 20, 5, 5),

NameError: name 'ReLU' is not defined
```

I changed the code to `activation_fn=linear`, and I got similar error.

Do you know why the defined activation functions were not recognized?

Comment: Shouldn't that be `activation_fn=network3.ReLU` (or `network3.linear`), since you're not importing `ReLU` (or `linear`) by name

Comment: Your code (which uses `linear` instead of `ReLu`) doesn't match your error message. The line numbers don't match up, either.

Comment: I edited the typos when copying the values from Jupyternotebook into the questions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @khelwood commented when importing modules using `import network3` you need to provide the namespace to access the functions and classes defined inside `network3`:

```
network3.ReLu
network3.linear
network3.ConvPoolLayer
```

To be possible to use simply `ReLu`, `linear` and `ConvPoolLayer` you can change your import line to one of the following:

```
from network3 import *
```

or

```
from network3 import ReLu, linear, ConvPoolLayer
```

Comment: I thought ```from network3 import *``` meant to import *everything*, so why is it necessary to import individual function?

Comment: I said  _"**one** of the following"_. I will edit and split into two blocks to avoid misunderstandings

Comment: Hi Hemerson, do you know why in the original code, Michael Nielsen did not import the activation functions nor use the prefix network3. for the activation function? Was it an oversight?